# std::cin not working inside of a for loop

Tags: c++, gcc, mingw

I'm using mingw on windows. Maybe I'm dumb or it's an error, but cins inside of a for-loop are just not working.
This was the best code snippet I could image to demonstrate the problem...

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main()
{
  std::string x;
  for (int i; i < 10; i++)
  {
    char y;
    std::cin >> y;
    x += y;
  }
  std::cout << x;
}
```

If I compile and run, I don't get prompted with the input. It just runs trough. I thought maybe it's an input buffer thing, but I spammed a lot of cin.ignores, so that can't really be the problem.

Comment: You need to initialize `i`, otherwise it's UB to read from it.

Comment: int i equals... what?

Answer (score 2):

Your for loop doesn't initialize `i`, so you have UB when you compare it to `10`. Instead, you should initialize `i` like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
```

Assuming you want the loop to execute `10` times.